# Camel context started twice spring mvc java config

Tags: apache-camel, spring-java-config

I have a project spring mvc with camel without any xml config file.

My problem is that there are two context : Spring root WebApplicationContext and Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher', and a camel context is created on every context (camel-1 and camel-2), with the same routes. Thus, if I stop or suspend one route, she is stopped or suspended on only one context (WebApplicationContext). I would like to have the context camel only once. How can i do ?

ApplicationConfiguration.java

```
package sal.sfs.configuration;

    import sal.sfs.security.SfsSessionInfo;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "sal.sfs")
    @PropertySource(value = {"classpath:sfs.properties"})
    @Import({PersistenceConfiguration.class, SecurityConfiguration.class, SfsCamelConfiguration.class})
    public class ApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

        @Bean(name = "SFS")
        public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
            InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            viewResolver.setSuffix(".zul");
            return viewResolver;
        }

        /*
         * Configure ResourceHandlers to serve static resources like CSS/ Javascript etc...
         */
        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/");
            registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("/img/");
        }

    }
```

SfsCamelConfiguration.java

```
package sal.sfs.configuration;

import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import org.apache.camel.Route;
import org.apache.camel.spring.javaconfig.CamelConfiguration;
import org.apache.camel.spring.spi.SpringTransactionPolicy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("sal.sfs.camel")
@Import(PersistenceConfiguration.class)
public class SfsCamelConfiguration extends CamelConfiguration {

    @Resource
    PersistenceConfiguration persistenceConfiguration;

    @Bean
    public SpringTransactionPolicy camelTransactionPolicy() {
        SpringTransactionPolicy springTransactionPolicy = new SpringTransactionPolicy();
        springTransactionPolicy.setTransactionManager(persistenceConfiguration.transactionManager(persistenceConfiguration.entityManagerFactory().getObject()));
        springTransactionPolicy.setPropagationBehaviorName("PROPAGATION_REQUIRED");
        return springTransactionPolicy;
    }

}
```

SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java

```
package civadis.salaires.sfs.configuration;

import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

SpringMvcInitializer.java

```
package sal.sfs.configuration;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class SpringMvcInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{ApplicationConfiguration.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{ApplicationConfiguration.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/", "*"};
    }


    /*
    Also we have registered OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter to enable lazy loading of JPA entity graphs in view rendering phase
    */
    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
       return new Filter[]{ 
            new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter()
        };
    }    
}
```

Comment: What version of Camel do you use? Try with latest release

Comment: Hi Claus, I use the last version of camel 2.17.2 with spring version 4.2.5.

Answer (score 0):

It's Ok if I change my getServletConfigClasses() :

```
public class SpringMvcInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

...
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }
...
}
```